# Am I implementing strcpy_s incorrectly?

Tags: c++

I am getting this error message from the C++ compiler:

> 'strcpy_s’ was not declared in this scope

I have gone through many blogs, read documentation, trying to correct the issue. This is an assignment for secure coding, although I am not a programmer.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
    
void sampleFunc(char inStr[])
{
    char buf[10];
    buf[9] ='\0';
    strcpy_s(buf, inStr);
    cout << "\n" << buf << "\n";
    return;
}

int main(){
    char inStr[10];
    cout << "Enter String: ";
    cin >> inStr;
    sampleFunc(inStr);
}
```

Comment: `errno_t strcpy_s(char *restrict dest, rsize_t destsz, const char *restrict src);`.

Comment: What compiler are you using? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=msvc-160

Comment: VScode and I have also used an online compiler. I have gone through the documentation in the above link but sure if I was missing a header.

Comment: The reason I asked is that Visual C++ provides a templated version that captures the size where other compilers do not and you need to supply it yourself as shown in the first link. You may also need `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1` before you include string.h.

Comment: This seems more complex for the program but you are the expert. I have added a different implementation and it seems to work. It is using the strcpy_s so it should be more secure than just strcpy. void strcpy_s(char *dest, char *src)
{
  strcpy(dest, src);
}our opinion is valued.

Comment: @ Retired Ninja: I tried adding #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1 but not sure if it was before string.h. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

worth mentioning, apart from the argument count to `strcpy_s` , the reference [manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) says

> `strcpy_s` is only guaranteed to be available if **STDC_LIB_EXT1** is
> defined by the implementation and if the user defines
> **STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1** to the integer constant 1 before including string.h.

Thus the right usage is something as mentioned in the reference link above

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <string.h>

// and somewhere the the code

#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
    set_constraint_handler_s(ignore_handler_s);
    int r = strcpy_s(dst, sizeof dst, src);
    printf("dst = \"%s\", r = %d\n", dst, r);
    r = strcpy_s(dst, sizeof dst, "Take even more tests.");
    printf("dst = \"%s\", r = %d\n", dst, r);
#endif
```

Comment: I had read that strcpy_s takes three arguments and only two are presented but I was trying to find an alternative to strcpy that was more secure. Thanks for all your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`strcpy_s()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) takes three arguments, and you are only providing two.

```
errno_t strcpy_s(char *restrict dest, rsize_t destsz, const char *restrict src);
```

Unlike `strcpy()`, `strcpy_s()` requires that you provide the size of the destination buffer.

Try making the following modification to `sampleFunc()`:

```
void sampleFunc(char inStr[])
{
    char buf[10];
    buf[9] ='\0';
    strcpy_s(buf, 9, inStr);
    cout <<"\n" <<buf<<"\n";
    return;
}
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s: `template <size_t size> errno_t strcpy_s(char (&dest)[size], const char *src); // C++ only`

Comment: @theOtherMichael: strcpy_s(buf, 9, inStr); comes up with an error invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char*’